# How to position images side by side with a heading overlay in CSS (with a sticky table header underneath)

Tags: html, css

I've managed to place my three images side by side at the top of my webpage using this [tip](https://w3schoolsrus.github.io/howto/howto_css_images_side_by_side.html), but I can't seem to center my `h1` correctly. Here's my CSS for centering `h1`:

```
.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

I would like `h1` to be horizontally and vertically aligned over the images regardless of the size of the browser window.

I don't know if it matters, but I also have a table underneath the images for which the `th` tag's position is set to `sticky`, which may be interfering with the `h1` CSS.

Comment: Instead of absolute positioning, which won't be responsive. Try using a flex container with `display: flex` and use `align-items: center` with `justify-content: center` to center align content along the cross and main axis of the flex box. [MDN Flex Container Alignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container)

Comment: Whoa... that was easy! Thanks for helping this HTML/CSS newb out, Tanner!

Comment: Glad to help! Let me know if you have any other questions.